# I want to create a global dictionary that I can also mutate

Tags: scala, playframework

How can I do the following in play:

1. I need to create a globally accessible object in play so I can access it from all of my controllers.
2. This object will be a map of users objects.
3. If a lookup fails, I want to lock, perform a db call to lookup, and then set it in the globally accessible object (which is a map).

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible: yes, a good idea: probably not. Why do you want to do that? I'd prefer a regular db call whenever you need an user object. If you run in performance problems, use a cache.

Comment: I want it to be locally stored, I don't want to make an external call to the cache for this scenerio.

Comment: The question must be asked: why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is possible as it was part of Play prior to 2.3.x (4 I think) . But it was removed, as a DI approach is now favored. So if you implement something like this you would have to fight the framework which never a is happy path to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, I think you can come up a primitive cache using the DI and a combination of a [concurrent map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap).

In one of your guice modules, you can have something like the following.

```
import scala.collection.concurrent

@Provides @Named("localUserCache") @Singleton
private def provideLocalUserCache(): concurrent.Map[Long, User] = {
  concurrent.TrieMap[Long, User]()
}
```

Then, in your classes, wherever you need to use the cache, inject that map:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (@Named ("localUserCache") val cache: concurrent.Map[Long, User], ... ) { ... }
```

The `@Named` is used just for some additional clarity and can be removed if you only have one injected instance of a concurrent map.

Then, you can do the following:

```
cache.getOrElseUpdate(someId, getUserFromDb(someId))
```

Here, the `getUserFromDb(someId)` will only get executed if the corresponding key doesn't already exist in the map. From the documentation:

> If the specified key is not already in the map, computes its value using the given thunk op and enters it into the map.
>
> Since concurrent maps cannot contain null for keys or values, a NullPointerException is thrown if the thunk op returns null.

Also, to make things a bit more concise, you can replace the injected map with a injected instance that encapsulates the map. For ex.

```
@Singleton
class UserCache @Inject() {
  private val map: concurrent.Map[Long, User] = concurrent.TrieMap()

  def getUser(id: Long) = {
     map.getOrElseUpdate(id, getUserFromDb(id))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a singleton.

Somewhere in the controller

```
@Inject
private Users users;
```

Your actual class:

```
public class MyUsers implements Users ....
```

Guice module class:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Users.class).to(MyUsers.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

in *application.conf*

```
play.modules.enabled += "mypackage.MyModule"
```

Some documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

The same for scala:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection